# SQL Sum Accumulated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called "Receiving_Details" with these columns:

| Part ID | Part Condition | Qty | Received DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GOOD | 2 | 2023-04-23 1:30 PM |
| 2 | BAD | 1 | 2023-04-22 1:30 PM |
| 3 | GOOD | 5 | 2023-04-22 1:30 PM |
| 4 | GOOD | 7 | 2023-04-21 1:30 PM |
| 5 | GOOD | 1 | 2023-04-20 1:30 PM |
| 6 | BAD | 3 | 2023-04-19 1:30 PM |

And I have another another table called "Daily_Capacity" with these columns:

| Date | Part Condition | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-23 | GOOD | 107 |
| 2023-04-23 | BAD | 57 |
| 2023-04-22 | GOOD | 110 |
| 2023-04-22 | BAD | 92 |
| 2023-04-21 | GOOD | 137 |
| 2023-04-21 | BAD | 82 |

I need to write a query that returns a daily "Qty Acumulated" based on the table Receiving_Details, using the "Received DT" to order it. Then I need to identify which parts where received over the daily capacity indicated in Daily_Capacity table based on date and part condition.

The output I need is something like this:

| Part ID | Part Condition | Qty | Received DT | QTY Accumulated | Over Capacity? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1058 | GOOD | 2 | 2023-04-23 1:30 PM | 98 | False |
| 1059 | GOOD | 7 | 2023-04-23 1:31 PM | 105 | False |
| 1060 | GOOD | 1 | 2023-04-23 1:38 PM | 106 | False |
| 1061 | GOOD | 4 | 2023-04-23 1:45 PM | 110 | True |
| 1062 | GOOD | 1 | 2023-04-23 1:53 PM | 111 | True |
| 1063 | GOOD | 20 | 2023-04-23 1:58 PM | 131 | True |

Don't no how to start

Comment: How do the input and output relate? The `PART_ID`s are different, as well as the `Recieved DT`. The expected result does not seem to correspond to the sample data, or at least a clear explanation is needed on what logic is expected.

Comment: shouldn't the partId be in the capacity table?

Comment: Though this solution is very simple (running sum and joining ) your question is not clear enough. Please share some valid input utput data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get QtyAccumulated column by using `sum()over()` window funciton.

```
select PartID,  PartCondition,  Qty, ReceivedDT, sum(qty)over(partition by partID order by ReceivedDT ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as QTYAccumulated
from Receiving_Details
```

Please share relatable input output sample data for other part of solution.